# How to align Text vertically and horizontally inside of Container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to create button widget from scratch and here is the code I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  String _number;

  static const double _buttonMargin = 20.0;
  Button(this._number);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
        height: 50.0,
        width: 50.0,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(_buttonMargin),
        child: Text(
          _number,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ));
  }
}
```

I would like to know how can I align the numbers to be exactly in the middle of the container? The screenshot of what it looks like is attached.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the Text widget using `Align` & set the `alignment` property to `Alignment.center`.

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Text(
    _number,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  ),
),
```